# Find max date using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column which has date value for different records, and I need to fetch the date which has the maximum value. One or more records can have the same date. How can I proceed with this? Not understanding on where to start the code on this:

```
for i = 3 to last_lin
max_dat = ws.Range("C" & i).Value
Next
```

last_line is the last line of the record till which data needs to be verified. I have put value in this variable "max_dat". Now what next should be done? Please let me know.

Comment: Create the range as a variable and do Application.WorksheetFunction.Max on the range

Comment: `max_dat = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Range(ws.Cells(3,3),ws.Cells(last_lin,3)))`

Comment: @scott cranner - Thank you so much...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking an example case create the range as a variable and do Application.WorksheetFunction.Max on the range

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim max_dat As Date
Dim last_lin As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")

last_lin = 5
max_dat = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Range("C3:C" & last_lin))

Debug.Print max_dat

End Sub
```

Data in sheet

[image: Data]